# Как брать данные из firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Нужно извлечь из real-time database данные. Я прописал такой код

```
    private void getUsermenwomInfo()
{
    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()&&snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0)
            {
                String name=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                nameusercard.setText(name);
                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                    String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageosnovnoe);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

В ней прописал откуда именно и какие данные брать но когда запустил приложение данные не появились в shapeableimageview.
Почему оттуда не берутся данные?
Я начинающий андроид разработчик и буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: вот так выглядит моя real-time database]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из firebase выводить картинки которые хранятся в папке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461915/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-firebase-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: Каждый день вижу вопросы про firebase, неужели гугл  не выдаёт ничего

Comment: Не нашел. Мой метод не работает. А индусов не понимаю к сожалению